# How to make vscode work with playsound module?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-playsound

I have this very simple test code:

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound('alarmsound.wav')
```

alarmsound.wav is a file in the same directory. when I run it in a terminal, it works fine. But when I run it in VSCode, it blows up with the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Luca/Desktop/Python/own/playaudio.py", line 3, in <module>
    playsound('alarmsound.wav')
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
    Error 275 for command:
        open "alarmsound.wav" alias playsound_0.7197283376226026
    Cannot find the specified file.  Make sure the path and filename are correct.
```

It used to work in vscode before, now suddenly it blows up. what could be wrong?

Comment: How are you running the code? Chances are your current working directory isn't what you think it is, so by using relative path it prevents Python from finding the `.wav` file.

Comment: wow, that solved it! I wasn't aware that i was running from the parent directory of the actual directory i was supposed to run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're actually running the file from the directory where your sound file is in.

In my case, it was running Python from the *parent* directory of the folder with the `.wav` file.